# Deduplication of Dataframe returning empty object

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 csv files with similar columns. I am reading and concatenating them with the following code:

```
One = pd.read_csv("/Users/xxx/Documents/Domains/Malaysia - MAR.csv" )
Two = pd.read_csv("/Users/xxx/Documents/Domains/Malaysia - CR.csv" )


links_webtrends_my = pd.concat([One,Two])

links_webtrends_my = links_webtrends_my['Page']

links_webtrends_my = links_webtrends_my.to_frame(name='Page')
```

I then use this line to drop duplicates

```
links_webtrends_my = links_webtrends_my.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
```

When I do this, it deletes everthing in it. When I call `links_webtrends_my` afterwards, it doesnt return anything. I will appreciate guidance on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `inplace=True` the return object is NoneType.  Remove the assignment back to the variable when using `inplace=True`.

```
links_webtrends_my.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
```

OR remove the inplace=True parameter.

```
links_webtrends_my = links_webtrends_my.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```